# Compare diff() to 60 or 90 in if statement

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to check if $diff is less than 60 seconds or 90 seconds. Both times come from a database that is looped through and checked with an if statment from a sql server. when I try to make the if statment like this if ($diff <= '00:01:00') or if ($diff <= '00:01:30') it returns nothing, but there are some times that are less then 60 and 90.

```
$time1 = 22:33:11.5
$time2 = 22:32:13.3
$diff = $time2->diff($time1);
        if ($diff <= '0:1:0') {
        echo "Less than 60";
}

$time1 = 22:33:11.5
$time2 = 22:32:13.3
$diff = $time2->diff($time1);
        if ($diff <= '0:1:3') {
        echo "Less than 90";
}
```

diff would then equal '00:00:58' so it should echo out what I set but instead I get no results. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: `Diff` returns a [DateTime interval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). Check out that link, it can give you some information on how to format it. Checking for less than 1 minute should be easy, but checking for 90 seconds might need a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by doing this.

```
$diff = $diff->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

I didn't know I could set a date with the format in a variable.